# Recyclerview setOnClickListner assigned in Viewholder not working

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

Recyclerview setOnClickListner assigned in Viewholder not working

```
public static class MyDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    /

    public MyDataViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Clicked..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

not Working
please help me.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think your problem it's in the context you are passing to the makeText method... Try using getContext()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the solution was to remove this from the CardView.xml file.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

This attribute overrides any clickListener added to the view.

Comment: Thanks it was helpful